# Resume download in Phpseclib

Tags: php, download, sftp, phpseclib

How can I resume my Download in phpseclib ?

There is an option to resume upload by the $mode parameter in put() , but how can I can resume my download in phpseclib over sftp?

Answer (score 2):

Full answer as @maliayas mentioned in comment to avoid overwriting local files as 0 bytes should be:

```
$sftp->get('filename.remote', fopen('filename.local', 'ab'), filesize('filename.local'));
```

Comment: Be aware, that after every iteration you have to call [`clearstatcache()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) before doing another call on `filesize()`on the local file else PHP will display the size it first read.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the third parameter - the $offset parameter - to be the size of the localfile. eg.

```
$sftp->get('filename.remote', 'filename.local', filesize('filename.local'));
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? Phpseclib opens local file with `fopen($local_file, 'wb');` which truncates it to zero length. It doesn't look like to be designed as a resume feature.

Comment: OK, found the solution. We should use `fopen('filename.local', 'ab')`. Updated your answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input with fopen('filename.local', 'ab') - saved my time :)